# Is there a system in place to moderate Stack Exchange usernames?

Tags: discussion, flags, display-names, offensive

I've recently come across a Stack Exchange user whose name could be considered offensive.

([Link](https://stackexchange.com/users/6241150/asshole-the-dick-sucker)) [Content warning: Offensive/vulgar language]

I've looked around and found no way of reporting the profile. Is there a system in place to flag and resolve issues regarding usernames which could be considered offensive?